# Kendo AutoComplete - keyboard navigation doesn't work anymore after custom rows

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, autocomplete

In order to display more data than just the product name alone I've changed the rendering of the AutoComplete control. The control renders exactly like intended, but when I use the arrow keys to navigate to a row it will not select a row by itself.

However, when hover over a row first and *then* start using the arrow keys it works just like it used to work and I can use enter so select. Only the highlighting is lacking.

I would like to achieve the following:

- To get arrow down working straight after typing instead of having to hover over the rows first
- To get the selected row to have a different style (like background color) so the user sees which row is selected

I have tried to intercept what AutoComplete does in terms of setting a class or style to the selected row but I wasn't successful in getting it to show what it does to the row as it will hide the moment I go into Firebug and other tools that achieve the same.

I also can't figure out why the first arrow down doesn't work. I assume the control can't find a row anymore now the layout got more complex by introducing the table with a head, but I'm not sure.

```
function CreateAutocompletes() {
    $('[data-autocomplete]').each(function (index, element) {
        var requestUrl = $(element).attr('data-action');
        var elm = $(element).autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            source: function(request, response) {
                var warehouseId = $('#WarehouseId').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: requestUrl,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        query: request.term,
                        warehouseId: warehouseId
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        response($.map(data, function(item) {
                            return {
                                value: item.Name,
                                realValue: item.ProductId,
                                label: item.Name,
                                ProductId: item.ProductId,
                                SKU: item.SKU,
                                Name: item.Name,
                                Stock: item.Stock,
                                Ordered: item.Ordered,
                                BulkOrdered: item.BulkOrdered,
                                Underway: item.Underway,
                                Surplus: item.Surplus
                            };
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                var hiddenFieldName = $(this).attr('data-value-name');
                $('#' + hiddenFieldName).val(ui.item.ProductId);
                $(this).parent().next().children().first().focus();
            }
        }).data("ui-autocomplete");

        elm._renderItem = function (table, item) {
            return $("<tr class='ui-menu-item'></tr>")
              .append("<td><a>" + item.SKU + "</a></td><td><a>" + item.Name + "</a></td>" +
                "<td><a>" + item.Stock + "</a></td><td><a>" + item.Ordered + "</a></td><td><a>" + item.BulkOrdered + "</a></td>" +
                "<td><a>" + item.Underway + "</a></td>")
              .appendTo(table);
        };

        elm._renderMenu = function(ul, items) {
            var self = this;
            ul.append("<table class='table table-striped'><thead><tr class='ui-menu-item'><th>" + Translations.SKU + "</th><th>" + Translations.Name + "</th>" +
                "<th>" + Translations.Stock + "</th><th>" + Translations.Ordered + "</th><th>" + Translations.BulkOrdered + "</th><th>" + Translations.Underway + "</th>" +
                "</tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>");
            $.each(items, function(index, item) {
                self._renderItemData(ul.find("tbody"), item);
            });
        };
    });
}
```

I only need to comment out elm._renderItem and elm._renderMenu to return to the previous behaviour and that works like intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more study I found out that it tries to set a class called `ui-state-focus` on the `li`-tag and the `a`-tag contained in it then gets a background and a border.

Since in the modified version above the `a`-tag was repeated a few times it might have choked on that. I have created an ugly hack that works by creating a faux table with spans with fixed widths, this even works with headers:

```
   elm._renderItem = function (table, item) {
        return $("<li role='option' class='option' style='width:920px'>")
            .append("<a><div style='width:120px' >" +
                item.SKU +
                "</div><div style='width:500px; overflow:hidden'>" +
                item.Name +
                "</div><div style='width:70px'>" +
                item.Stock +
                "</div><div style='width:70px'>" +
                item.Ordered +
                "</div><div style='width:70px'>" +
                item.BulkOrdered +
                "</div><div style='width:70px'>" +
                item.Underway +
                "</div></a></li>")
            .appendTo(table);
    };

    elm._renderMenu = function(ul, items) {
        var self = this;
        ul.append("<li class='autocomplete-header'><div style='width:120px'>" +
            Translations.SKU +
            "</div><div style='width:500px;overflow:hidden'>" +
            Translations.Name +
            "</div><div style='width:70px'>" +
            Translations.Stock +
            "</div><div style='width:70px'>" +
            Translations.Ordered +
            "</div><div style='width:70px'>" +
            Translations.BulkOrdered +
            "</div><div style='width:80px'>" +
            Translations.Underway +
            "</div></li>");
        $.each(items, function(index, item) {
            self._renderItemData(ul, item);
        });
    };
```

It's not pretty and probably you should do the column widths with a class instead of hard-coded values but this at least should get you on the way if you experience the same problem.

If there's a better solution I would like to hear it!